# Active directory error when trying to getAttributes with objectGUID - Couldn't perform DN to Data source mapping

Tags: active-directory, ldap

we are having some problem with active directory from java ldap, we first create an LdapContext and then try to bind with objectGUID like that:

```
ctx.getAttributes("<GUID=58f20049-931e-4b69-ba5f-8b8654e9d8e9>");
```

this is working perfect in our development environment , but in customer site with their active directory forest we get an exception:
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - Couldn't perform DN to Data source mapping]; remaining name ''

we've been trying hard to understand the problem but no luck,
any help please?

Thank you